# files not including in php & htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess

I am building a MVC and I am including my css file through echo from separate `header.php`

```
echo "<link type='text/css' href='".DOMAIN."public/assets/".$file."?v=".version."' />";
```

And in css file

```
body {
    background : gray;
}
```

It just printing the ehco throug above step but it is not including it as css file. But when I simply put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/assets/custom/style.css">
```

in `header.php` its working fine. What mistake I am doing.
Here is my `.htaccess` code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have tried many solutions for this.

Comment: You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: but i was trying in localhost

Comment: after your suggestion I tried `<base href="http://localhost/Path/">`
and include my file
`<link href="public/custom/error.css">` but didn't work

Comment: Please try to give complete complete path once and try then?

Comment: Yes I tried `<base href="/">` & `<link href="path/to.css">` now when I click `Open in new tab` from dev console of the browser it is showing my file which coded but not loading the styles from that file.

Comment: I tried `<style><?php include 'public/custom/error.css'; ?></style>` it works but i didn't need that method.

Comment: _“it is showing my file which coded”_ - well then you obviously do not have a path problem any more, and the problem must be something else. What does the browser console say? Which styles do you see get applied and from where, when you inspect the body element in dev tools?

Comment: No styles are applied.